# Java editing a database in java with a wamp server

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Im 12 and i am learning java that causes some problems :D. Because i cant realy program that much so here's my problem.
I want to edit a Database in Java and my database server is running on Wamp so i have PhpMySql . I created a database and tried to let it show in Java well thats working now i want to edit the database through java. I thought this code might work:

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery("UPDATE  `martbank`.`users` SET  `Balance` =  
  '"+Saldo.getText()+"' WHERE  `users`.`User_Id` ="
            +Nummer.getText()
            +" AND  `users`.`Surname` =  '"+lastname.getText()
            +"' AND  `users`.`Firstname` =  '"+firstname.getText()
            +"' AND  `users`.`Pin` = '"+Password.getText()
            +"' AND  `users`.`Balance` = '"+Saldo.getText()
            +"' AND  `users`.`Password` =  '"+Password.getText()+"' LIMIT 1 ;");
```

If i can get help i am very happy to hear about it.

Comment: Learn how to use prepared statements first of all!

Comment: First tip, use a `PreparedStatement`. Second tip, rename your variables in order to not start with capitalized letters.

Comment: @Michael-O care to post an example of moving the code into `PreparedStatement`?

Comment: What exactly is the problem with that code? SQL Exception? Unexpected updates on the database?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, no I don't. This has been written a zillion times on SO and there is Google. There is no need to reinterate the obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is - sorry to say - very unspecific, but let me try to give you a little insight.

First, you should get familiar with JDBC and the concept of connecting to a database and executing queries. The [Oracle Learing Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html) on this is a perfect start. It will give you simple out-of-the-box examples on how to use a JDBC driver, connect and how to use a database connection.

After that, make sure that you know what a `PreparedStatement` is and how to use it. The way you're composing queries allows [SQL injection attacs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) much too easy.

Hope this answer empowers you to get in touch with Java and Databases.

Comment: Ok Then ill do that im a beginner and on a age of 12 so i dont know much of Java. Ill learn that.

Comment: @MarttiGroenen You might want to check the complete Trail "Learning the Java Language" starting here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html

Comment: @MarttiGroenen It's great you started so early. Good Luck

Comment: Im Starting early on my 12th age (Im 12 :D).

Comment: @zero0 Thanks for the code! Now i can learn Java without Youtube.

Comment: @MarttiGroenen Youtube? Where had all those good old-fashioned books gone :-) I wish you all the best!